# Is it possible to do mysql database transactions and rollbacks with php?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

example: making a payment transfer from user A to user B.
Account of user A: -10 USD
Account of user B: +10 USD

if there is an transaction, and something goes wrong, everything gets undone. So with transactions it will not happen that account of user A gets decreased by 10, while account of user B does not get increased by 10.

I know the java people make use of transactions and rollbacks all over the place. But I've never heard of PHP-guys doing that.

Answer (score 5):

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "", "", "");
$db->autocommit(FALSE);
if ($db->query("INSERT ..."))
    $db->commit();
else
    $db->rollback();
```

Make sure your tables use `InnoDB` engine: `MyISAM` does not support transactions.

**Comment update**:

`InnoDB` is one of two major storage engines used by `MySQL`, the other one being `MyISAM`.

`MySQL` comes with `InnoDB` support compiled in by default and in fact it takes some effort to disable it.

I've never heard of `MySQL` with `InnoDB` disabled even by cheapest of the hosters.

Comment: you would need an own server for innoDB, since no cheap hoster has it, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you use pdo, it also has transaction support

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php

like was already said, make sure you use the innoDB storage engine.

Comment: Is that thread-safe? What if 20 users start things at pretty much the same time, so that several threads do stuff like that pretty much the same time?

Comment: @thanks: I think the most basic example to give is to say that they get queued up. Databases are designed to handle things like this, and 20 users starting transactions at almost-all-at-once should be completely negligible.